# excecuting crontab linux in hour:minutes:[miliseconds]

Tags: linux, bash, cron

How can i run bash file in hour : minutes : milliseconds

like 8 : 30 : 800(milliseconds)

This is my code :

```
30 8 * * * cd /home/req && sh notify.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
30 8 * * * sleep .8 ; cd /home/req && sh notify.sh
```

The above code will execute notify.sh sometime after 8:30 and 800 ms.  We can do better, but we'll never be exact.  Consider rather than hard coding the sleep for 800 ms (.8 seconds) we determine the sleep time from the current time and sleep until the time will be more closely 8:30:00.800 .

It depends on your requirements.  If you need to execute notify after 8:30:00.800, my solution works.  If you want to get closer to the exact time, we have to be a little smarter.

Comment: it have some delay , do you have a more accurate solution ?

Comment: Hi @hosseinpanahi, strictly speaking - increasing the time delay doesn't necessarily increase accuracy.   The accuracy issue is that cron has 1 minute resolution - and you shouldn't expect cron to start your cronjob exactly at beginning of the minute.  If cron does start at exactly the beginning of the minute, the solution I gave you is fine.  But for more accuracy, change the sleep from the .8 constant to a function of the current time.  Imagine cron  starts you at 8:30.00.010 - you should only  sleep for .79 seconds.